# extract RGB values from linear colourmap made using LinearSegmentedColormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I would like to create a linear colourmap from a list of discrete colors, and extract the underlying RGB values. I've managed to do the first step using the example script in the matplotlib document.

```
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

colors = [(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)]
colormap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('colormapX', colors, N=100)

x = np.arange(0, np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.cos(X) * np.sin(Y) * 10

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=colormap)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

This colormap is based on 100 colours that were derived from the interpolation of the the original three colours. How do I extract an ndarray with the RGB values of these 100 colours?

Comment: Maybe my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885178/how-can-i-see-the-rgb-channels-of-a-given-image-with-python) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's available directly somewhere, or if one can ask the `colormap` to evaluate a given value (return the colour corresponding to a given number), but you can make the list yourself in this simple case:

```
def color_interpolation(c1, c2, fraction=0.5):
    return ((1.-fraction)*c1[0] + fraction*c2[0],
            (1.-fraction)*c1[1] + fraction*c2[1],
            (1.-fraction)*c1[2] + fraction*c2[2],)

def make_color_interpolation_list(colors, N):
    n_colors = len(colors)
    n_steps_between_colors = N/(n_colors-1)
    fraction_step = 1. / n_steps_between_colors
    color_array = np.zeros((N,3))
    color_index = 0
    while color_index < n_colors-1:
        fraction_index = 0
        while fraction_index < n_steps_between_colors:
            index = color_index*n_steps_between_colors+fraction_index
            color_array[index]= color_interpolation(c1=colors[color_index],
                                    c2=colors[color_index+1],
                                    fraction=fraction_index*fraction_step)
            fraction_index += 1
        color_index += 1
    if index != len(color_array)-1:
        color_array[-1] = colors[-1]
    return color_array
```

Comment: thanks this is almost perfect, except under some combinations of parameters it adds unwanted black hues to the end of the colormap. for example try [red, green, blue] and [N = 17]

Comment: I seem to never remember that not all numbers divide neatly into others... Make `index = color_index*n_steps_between_colors+fraction_index` inside the deepest `while` and in the end test whether or not that `index` is different to `len(color_array)-1`. If it is different make `color_array[-1] = colors[-1]`. [Edited on the code above] It's a jerry rigged solution after all.